# Dilution terminology

Tags: solutions, terminology

For thing like 8× dilution, that would be like 1 ml of a solution and then 7 ml of something like water to dilute right? Would 50 ml solution and 50 ml water be a 2× dilution? I’m a bit unsure about the terminology. If I an OD of 0.123 from a sample diluted 5×, would multiply 0.123 by 5 to get the real OD?

Comment: It seems your right, but what's OD?

Comment: Optical density.

Answer (score 3):

You are right.  The × in 8× refers to the fold-change in concentration between the concentrated source and diluted solution.

$$\mathrm{DF = \frac{C_{stock}}{C_{working}}}$$ where $\mathrm{C_{stock}}$ and $\mathrm{C_{working}}$ are the concentrations of a stock solution and the desired final concentration, respectively.

The concentration of the working solution can be expanded:

$$\mathrm{C_{working} = \frac{C_{stock} V_{stock}}{V_{working}} = \frac{C_{stock} V_{stock}}{V_{stock}+V_{diluent}}}$$ where $\mathrm{V_{stock}}$ is the volume of the stock solution and $\mathrm{V_{diluent}}$ is the volume of diluent (e.g. pure water) added.

Plugging back into the DF equation:

$$\mathrm{DF = \frac{C_{stock}}{\frac{C_{stock} V_{stock}}{V_{stock}+V_{diluent}}} = \frac{V_{stock}+V_{diluent}}{V_{stock}}}$$

Comment: so would 50/50 of each be a 2x dilution or..

Comment: Yep, you're right again.